# "OSError: Unable to open file (file signature not found)" trying to run "bert_model = BertModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased", from_tf=True)"

Tags: python, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

A few weeks ago, the following ran successfully:

```
bert_model = BertModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased", from_tf=True)
```

I've just re-run the exact same code and I'm now getting this error:

> OSError: Unable to open file (file signature not found)

I tried adding `, force_download=True` to the parameters but still get the same error.

What's causing this and what do I need to change to fix it?

Comment: Which version were you running the previous model on, and what is the current version?

Comment: When I run 'pip freeze | grep transformers' it outputs ''transformers==2.4.1". I assume thats the current version on my laptop. Not sure how to get details on what the previous was. Do you know? Either way, if the previous version was different, what do I need to change to fix this?

Comment: If you are not loading from a TF checkpoint, but instead use a pretrained model that is already a PyTorch model, ahve you tried simply disabling the `from_tf` parameter?

Comment: For me, downgrading to same version with which the model was trained fixed the error. I trained it on a machine with 3.5.0 but I was trying to test it on a machine with 3.5.1 Reverted to 3.5.0 and I am able to use the model without from_tf=True flag